# Get path to npm module folder (with no main)

Tags: node.js, npm

How do I get path to the folder that contains npm module?

I tried `require.resolve` but I got `Error: Cannot find module 'bower-strapless'`.
 (even though I had installed the module locally).

The module does not have a `main` in `package.json` -- does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that if there is no `main` in `package.json`, you can't just specify a module name — you have to provide a path to (any) file that actually exists. And then it is possible to use `path.dirname` to get to the package root.

In my case I needed `less` subfolder, so I used the following: `path.dirname(require.resolve('bower-strapless/less/bootstrap.less'))`.